# how can i make a sprite image (png) move on key in pygame

Tags: pygame

for some reason i cant seem to get an image to be able to move on the pygame screen. I get no errors the screen just lags and when I try to close it, windows tells me that the app isn't responding.

This is the code I tried and all it gives me is a screen with an image on it and does nothing

```
#this is a new rpg game that im trying to build
import pygame as pg
import os
###################
pg.init()
###################

def read(num=-1):
    with open("data/settings.txt", mode="r") as f:
        data = f.readlines()
        if num == -1:
            return len(data)
        return data[num].strip('\n')

fullscreen = read(6)

info = pg.display.Info()
m_width, m_height = info.current_w, info.current_h
[width, height] = [1000, 750] if fullscreen == "Off" else [m_width, m_height]
screen = pg.display.set_mode((width, height))
x = 0
y = 0
speed = 3

edin = height // 15

def skin(name, size=(edin, edin)):
    return pg.transform.scale(pg.image.load(f'data/images/{name}.png'), size).convert_alpha()

lava = skin('ground/grass1', (edin * 2, edin * 3))

keys = pg.key.get_pressed()

while True:
    if keys[pg.K_q]:
        pg.quit()
    if keys[pg.K_w]:
        y -= speed
    if keys[pg.K_s]:
        y += speed
    if keys[pg.K_d]:
        x += speed
    if keys[pg.K_a]:
        x -= speed

        
    screen.blit(lava, (x, y))
    pg.display.flip()
```

Comment: You need an event loop; `keys = pg.key.get_pressed()` has to be inside your main loop; you also have to clear the screen each frame.